# Laravel routing regex

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, laravel, laravel5

```
Route::get('{hash}/{hpx?}/{wpx?}', 'FileController@show')->where(['hash' => '/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i','hpx' => '[0-9]+','wpx' => '[0-9]+'])->name('file.get');
```

Имеется такой роут,  но регулярка для hash не срабатывает на хэш. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам следует ее поменять на

```
[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}
```

по аналогии со второй и третьей.